# Merge structurally different MySQL tables on a common value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 2 tables to a new table based on a shared value, but not having much luck.
Here's what I've got.

Table1:

```
id        |name     |
----------|---------|
1         |test1    |
```

Table2:

```
id        |name     |location |color    |
----------|---------|---------|---------|
1         | test1   |  10     |  blue   |
```

What I'm after here is a new table (Table3) that takes "name" from Table1 and matches it up against name from Table2 and then sticks the matching results into Table3. Anything that doesn't match table 1 should be ignored. So if I had "test99" in Table2, but not in Table1, don't put it in Table3.

Everything I've read says this shouldn't be hard to do, but I'm just not having any luck with it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: inner join table1 and table2 on name

Comment: Here's a brief tutorial on [MySql Joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm). Also, You better "link" the tables with a numeric field (like id) and not a textual one like name. Also there's no point in saving the name twice

Comment: Yeah, you'll run into an issue potentially linking on text, where you eventually have test42 in one table and test 42 in the other (spacing issues) or you'll have one with a space before or after in one table and not the other....it's probably fine for trivial stuff, but once this grows beyond a few records, it's less than ideal to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Table2.Name, Table2.Location, Table2.Colour
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Name = Table1.Name
```

Although I noticed you have Id which might be assumed is your Primary Key and Foreign Key ? If so try

```
SELECT Table2.Name, Table2.Location, Table2.Colour
FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Id= Table1.Id
```

Comment: Some variation of this is what I ended up using. Thanks a bunch for the help! Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a select into table.

```
Select * INTO Table3
FROM Table2 
WHERE Table2.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Table1)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `SELECT ... INTO` syntax. Look at  the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: You would just have to add the table3 with the same structure and adjust it use Insert Into then instead..
INSERT INTO Table3 
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM Table1)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use INSERT ... SELECT -syntax and use JOIN.

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id, name, location, color)
SELECT t.id, t2.name, t.location, t.color FROM table1 AS t JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```